# Optimal way of creating a fixed size thread pool in Java using the Executors service

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

I am using the `Executors` framework in Java to create thread pools for a multi-threaded application, and I have a question related to performance.

I have an application which can work in realtime or non-realtime mode. In case it's realtime, I'm simply using the following:

```
THREAD_POOL = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

But in case it's not realtime, I want the ability to control the size of my thread pool.
To do this, I'm thinking about 2 options, but I don't really understand the difference, and which one would perform better.

Option 1 is to use the simple way:

```
THREAD_POOL = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);
```

Option 2 is to create my own `ThreadPoolExecutor` like this:

```
RejectedExecutionHandler rejectHandler = new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
@Override
public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
    try {
        executor.getQueue().put(r);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
};          
THREAD_POOL = new ThreadPoolExecutor(threadPoolSize, threadPoolSize, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10000), rejectHandler);
```

I would like to understand what is the advantage of using the more complex option 2, and also if I should use another data structure than `LinkedBlockingQueue`? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking at the source code you'll realize that:

```
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);
```

is **equivalent** to:

```
return new ThreadPoolExecutor(threadPoolSize, threadPoolSize, 0L, MILLISECONDS,
                              new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
```

Since it doesn't provide explicit `RejectedExecutionHandler`, default `AbortPolicy` is used. It basically throws `RejectedExecutionException` once the queue is full. But the queue is unbounded, so it will never be full. Thus this executor accepts inifnite<sup>1</sup> number of tasks.

Your declaration is much more complex and quite different:

- `new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10000)` will cause the thread pool to discard tasks if more than 10000 are awaiting.
- I don't understand what your `RejectedExecutionHandler` is doing. If the pool discovers it cannot put any more runnables to the queue it calls your handler. In this handler you... try to put that `Runnable` into the queue again (which will <del>fail in like 99% of the cases</del> block). Finally you swallow the exception. Seems like `ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy` is what you are after.

  Looking at your comments below seems like you are trying to block or somehow throttle clients if tasks queue is too large. I don't think blocking inside `RejectedExecutionHandler` is a good idea. Instead consider `CallerRunsPolicy` rejection policy. Not entirely the same, but close enough.

To wrap up: if you want to limit the number of pending tasks, your approach is almost good. If you want to limit the number of concurrent threads, the first one-liner is enough.

<sup>1 - assuming 2^31 is infinity</sup>

Comment: The `RejectedExecutionHandler` is actually blocking, the call to `executor.getQueue().put(r);` will block until the queue frees up, so in the end my handler allows to keep a bounded queue without aborting any task. Unless I'm mistaken. +1 for the other details.

Comment: @CharlesMenguy: thank you for clarification, my bad, I'll update my question. But what do you want to achieve by blocking inside `RejectedExecutionHandler`? I believe it might have some really unexpected side effects like blocking caller thread. Maybe you need `CallerRunsPolicy`?

Comment: Actually after looking at it, `CallerRunsPolicy` sounds really promising for what I want to do, I will give it a try thanks ! Maybe you can add that in the answer and I will accept your answer.